# I can not connect to Socket.io room after disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client-server, real-time

On the first connection users successfully join rooms. However, after disconnection, room re-join fails. This code returns room as `undefined` when I try to connect after room disconnect.

Any good ideas how to deal with Socket.io re-connections?

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function onConnection(socket){
   socket.on('adduser', function(data){
      socket.room=data.room ; 
      socket.join(socket.room)
          })

   })

socket.on('drawing', function(points) {
       console.log("on room"+ socket.room)//logs undefined on reconnect 
        io.to(socket.room).emit('drawing', points);

console.log("broadcasting")
 });
```

*on disconnect:*

```
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
       console.log(socket.room)

       socket.leave(socket.room);

})
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect(':3000');

socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log("emit socket")
    socket.emit('adduser', data);
  })
```

Comment: Where is data.room defined? And what happens on the server side when a disconnect occurs?

Comment: ooh missed to add this!  im using dynamic rooms so rooms are defined on client side and sent to socket on "adduser" (i just edited the code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems that connection is not closed when a user disconnects because of Socket.io default behavior

this can be fixed by [forcing new connection on loading](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/700)
so on client side replace:

```
var socket=io.connect(':3000')
```

with

```
var socket=io.connect(':3000', {'force new connection': false})
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me **after disconnecting** the socket connection to the server using `socket.disconnect()` you can use

> socket.connect()

To establish a **connection** back to the **server** again.